# Функция обрезки поддомена

Tags: php

Есть функция обрезки поддомена и вывода домена:

```
function GET_DOMAIN($url) {
$pieces = parse_url($url);
$domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs))                      {
return $regs['domain'];
}
return false;
}
```

Всё работает, но при вводе

http://**s**.zat.su выдаёт zat.su

а при вводе

http://**ss**.zat.su выдаёт ss.zat.su, что является неправильным.

Не могу понять, почему так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Не могу понять, почему так

Потому что в регулярку включена точка, как разрешенный символ, фактически, zat.su в этом примере будет воспринят, как доменная зона:

```
[a-z\.]{2,6}
```

В первом примере она не совпадет, потому что регулярка исключает однобуквенные домены:

```
[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63} // один символ + последовательность от одно до шестиидесяти трех символов
```

Задачка же решается просто

```
$words = explode('.', $domain);
if (sizeof($words) < 2) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Provided URL doesn\'t contain second-level domain');
}
return implode('.', array_slice($words, -2));
```

Comment: @Etki, при вводе без поддомена отдаёт http://zat.su, а нужно zat.su

Comment: @Rammsteinik, переменная $domain так названа потому, что в ней предполагается наличие домена, а не урла. И вообще я подразумевал, что это вставляется в середину функции

    function GET_DOMAIN($url) {
        $pieces = parse_url($url);
        $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
        $words = explode('.', $domain);
        if (sizeof($words) < 2) {
            return false;
        }
        return implode('.', array_slice($words, -2));
    }